# Is it possible to overuse ajax in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This might sound like a silly question, but recently I came across a project someone else worked on here at work. Its an ASP.NET Web Forms project and its completely ajax'ed. However, its not done the traditional way using `UpdatePanel` or partial postbacks. Its done using jQuery `.ajax` calls that call C# WebMethod's in the page's code behind. An example in JavaScript might be like this:

```
function SaveThisForm() {
    var params = {};
    params.firstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
    params.lastName= $('#txtLastName').val();

    var handler = function(msg) {
        if (msg.d != '0') {
            alert('Form Saved!');
            // Do something else
        } else {
            alert('Something is wrong!');
            // Do Something
        }
    };

    doAjaxCallWithParams("MyPage.aspx/SaveForm", JSON.stringify(params), handler);
}
```

And the `MyPage.aspx.cs` might look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveForm(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var dbAccess = new Customer();
    Customer.FirstName = firstName;
    Customer.LastName = lastName;
    Customer.Save();

    return Customer.CustomerId.ToString();
}
```

Its pretty much the same kind of thing for retrieving data, deleting data and updating data. This probably isn't too bad but some some drop downs on the page will change data based on the customer that pulls up. To do this, he has a C# WebMethod function that loads the data from the database and renders the dropdown from the WebMethod and uses jQuery (something like `$('#myCityDiv').html(msg.d)`) to place the dropdown in the HTML page.

My question I guess is, is this a good practice? Or is it better to use UpdatePanel's and partial postbacks?

Comment: Its personal opinion I guess.. but wow does this sort of stuff get out of hand quick. You would do well to investigate a front end MVC style framework.. like Kendo, Knockout, Backbone, Angular, etc. It makes the jQuery spaghetti much nicer to deal with when the front end gets bigger.

Comment: When I used to do webforms, I found that that the update panels and partial postbacks were both too heavy, and too hidden (ie I had no idea what asp.net was doing) so I opted for a method similar to that you've described. It gets out of hand fairly quickly without any sort of framework though.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Do you have a favorite MVC client? I've used Knockout before and I actually like that one.

Comment: I liked Knockout to begin with. I have become quite a big fan of Angular in recent months though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is always: **`It Depends`**

I started with a webforms project that ended up being developed for more than 6 years.  While that was still in maintenance mode, I was introduced to MVC in another project.  The difference is night and day.  MVC is more of the original web programming pattern-- post what you need, when you need it.

The key factor you need to keep in mind is performance.  With that webforms app, my `UpdatePanel`s would post back for a certain section, but all `ViewState` for the page had to be posted to the server, all PostBack and event logic was then processed, and all the new `ViewState` and just the changed html had to be re-downloaded to the client.  For a simple gridview with a lot of controls and only 10 rows, there was upwards of 600k of data in **EACH** direction.  Remember that webforms work off a single `<form>` element.

MVC tends to buck ViewState and use several different views and `<form>` elements.  If you need to page your Widget Grid, you can post the new page index to a 'PageWidgetGrid' action that will return you the html for the new grid page. If I was moving from page 1 to page 2, it would be 1 byte for the posted value (`2` is treated as a string in this case).  Without the ViewState hindrance, I would be at 1 byte uploaded and maybe 2 KB downloaded.

However, I agree that the `WebMethod` approach is extremely cumbersome when it is mixed in with other page logic, especially when some devs may not understand that `SessionState` and other non-static/shared code in the page are not available in `WebMethod`s.  In my opinion, if development is ongoing, you may be better off starting to convert the project to a combination of webforms and MVC.  Webforms and ViewState don't lend themselves well to an overly-complex front-end, whereas MVC tends to emphasize granular developer control over the front-end.  Breaking away from webforms will make it easier to integrate with those other suggested frameworks in your question's comments-- things like Knockout, KendoUI, etc.

If you're stuck using webforms, you'll have to incorporate some workarounds that MVC doesn't have to do. Examples are for KnockOut.js:

```
<!-- doesn't work -->
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkChangeVisibility" runat="server" 
      data-bind="checked: isRowVisible" />

<!-- renders as: -->
<span data-bind="checked: isRowVisible">
    <input id="chkChangeVisibility" type="checkbox" name="chkChangeVisibility" />
</span>
```

You would need to set these attributes that webforms can't recognize in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkChangeVisibility.InputAttributes["data-bind"] = "checked: isRowVisible";
}
```

from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153735/Using-KnockoutJS-in-your-ASP-NET-applications

* I'm not extremely familiar with the front-end MVC library stuff (e.g., Knockout-- I use ASP.NET MVC all the time on the backend and serving views, just not a lot of single-page app experience), so I don't know if this particular code sample is relevant.  I do know it's not fun doing UI stuff with webforms.